# How is the position of a subject array pointer determined in a preg_replace_callback's callback function?

Tags: arrays, pointers, position, preg-replace-callback

How is the position of a $subject_array pointer determined in a preg_replace_callback's callback function?  I.e. What is the numeric key?
e.g.

```
$final_array = preg_replace_callback("/pattern/",
    create_function(
        '$matches',
        '[WHAT IS MY ARRAY POSITION? ($foo = ...)]; return $foo);'
    ), $subject_array);
```

**EDIT**

I want Foo, Bar, baZ.  The following doesn't work:

```
$rgData = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz');
$rgData = preg_replace_callback('/(\w)(\w)(\w)/', 
    function($rgMatches) use (&$rgData)
{
    var_dump(key($rgData));//see this debug
    next($rgData);
    if (key($rgData)==2) {
        return strtoupper($rgMatches[2]);
    } else {
        return strtoupper($rgMatches[0]);
    }
}, $rgData);
    var_dump($rgData);//see this debug
```

or maybe more simply, I want Foo, bAr, baZ:

```
$rgData = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz');
$rgData = preg_replace_callback('/(\w)(\w)(\w)/', 
    function($rgMatches) use (&$rgData)
{
    var_dump(key($rgData));//see this debug
    next($rgData);
    return strtoupper($rgMatches[key($rgData)]);
}, $rgData);
    var_dump($rgData);//see this debug
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, Alma, thanks for helping.  I found the reason you may have not understood me.  The answer I was looking for was too easy.  The answer is key().  Sorry for the hassle.  Thanks!